# Flickering Screen caused by Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, screen, flicker

I'm experiencing some strange flickering of the screen that I am unable to solve. I am not sure where its coming from, I've never seen this before. Anyone else had this issue?

I am coding in swift and using Interface Builder with auto layout.

Sometimes a random button or action can cause the layout to start flickering, it looks like its cropping and resizing itself and it does this about 10 times in a second until it goes back to normal.

PS: All my constraints are fine, and the buttons are not supposed to affect or change any constraints. This happens rarely and randomly.

Answer (score -1):

I've found that the menu: editor -> resolve auto layout issues

cures a lot of ills